# Between query in mongoDb by using start date and end Date (IST)

Tags: mongodb

I am able to get data by using below query for integer from my table of mongoDb by using umongo UI Interface.

```
{ sequence: { $gt: 4035 } }
{sequence:{$gte:4035,$lte:4035}}
```

Both above queries are working fine
 but in the same table or collection I have one column schedules inside the schedules I have startDate endDate column
 by using this column I want to execute "between clause" on the basis of start date and end date like below but no records are showing .

```
{'schedules.start': {'$gte': "1-1-2014",'$lt': "14-1-2016"}}
```

or

```
{'schedules.start': {$gte: '1-1-2014',$lt: '14-1-2016'}}
```

or

```
{'schedules.start': {$gte: 1-1-2014,$lt: 14-1-2016}}
```

or

```
{ 'schedules': {'$gt': 'date':'Wed Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2014', '$lt': 'date' :'Wed Dec 31 05:30:00 IST 2014'}}
```

so I need between query on the basis of starDate and endDate.

My table structure:

```
 site--> schedules-->star(date):Wed Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 2014
                     end(date) :Wed Dec 31 05:30:00 IST 2014
```

Here I am attaching screen shot of my table.
  Thank you in advance

Comment: I formatted the code and table structure for you, but please edit it further and try to make the text more clear and readable. Also the promised screenshot is missing.

Comment: There's something very important here, what's the format of your date field? Because it seems to be plain text not an ISODate. If we're talking about plain text the solution is different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap it with an $and clause?

```
{
  $and: [
    {'schedules.startDate': {$gte: 1-1-2014}},
    {'schedules.endDate': {$lt: 14-1-2016}}
  ]
}
```

Obviously you'll need to adjust naming conventions to your model.

Comment: It's not necessary, AND is implicitily the default operator